# Просмотр нескольких записей через форму

Tags: mysql, база-данных, delphi

На форме имеется PageControl, по двойному нажати на запись в DBGrid отркывается вкладка с фреймом для просмотра/редактирования записи. Редактирование происходит через DB компоненты (dbedit...). Как можно реализовать открытие нескольких записей на просмотр/редактирование?

Comment: Вопрос не очень понятен - проблема в том, что нужно создать несколько страниц на PageControl и соответственно на каждой фрейм редактирования?

Comment: @MBO, проблема в том, что датасет  может работать толькой с одной записью. Я хочу узнать, как можно открывать несколько записей на редактирование одновременно.

Comment: Используйте не DB компоненты для отображения данных.